# Why does my webcam light turn on when I select A2DP Profile for my headphones?

Tags: bluetooth, webcam, headphones, a2dp

I think it is potentially a bug with the bluetooth implementation or something, but I couldn't really figure it out myself. Maybe you can help me out:

When I connect my bluetooth headphones, they are initially recoginized as a Headset Head Unit and everything is fine.
When I go to the Sound Settings and switch to A2DP for better sound quality, the LED of my webcam turns on. Why does this switch activate my webcam and how can I prevent it?
I feel very uneasy with the LED turned on all the time..

[image: When I select the A2DP Profile, the webcam LED is turned on.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found the reason by accident myself: The Webcam has an integrated microphone which is activated when I am in the sound settings. Thus, the LED is turned on.